# Issues regarding Java Util Map Entry Class

Tags: java, collections

If I only declare `import java.util.*;` then I cannot use Entry class, which throws a compile time exception at below code at Entry Class
error "cannot find symbol" at Entry class

```
Set<Entry<String, Integer>> ent = map1.entrySet();
        for(Entry<String,Integer> key: ent){
           System.out.println(" count : "+key.getValue()+" : "+key.getKey() );
        }
```

---

But If I declare like this as below

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
```

Now it will not throw any compile time error. Why So?

So my question is:  why do we have declare separately "`import java.util.Map.Entry;`" when we have already declared " `import java.util.*;` "

Comment: Because import java.util.* imports the top-level public classes of java.util. Not the nested classes. If your actual question is "why is that?", the answer is: because that's how the Java designers decided to specify the language. You can use `Map.Entry`, instead of `Entry`.

Comment: import is shallow and doesn't imported nested classes or packages eg `import java.*;` doesn't import anything as there is nothing at this level.

Answer (score 1):

At first, packages appear to be hierarchical, but they are **not**.

For example, the Java API includes a java.awt package, a java.awt.color package, a java.awt.font package, and many others that begin with java.awt.

However, the java.awt.color package, the java.awt.font package, and other java.awt.xxxx packages are not included in the java.awt package. The prefix java.awt (the Java Abstract Window Toolkit) is used for a number of related packages to make the relationship evident, but not to show inclusion.

Importing java.awt.* imports all of the types in the java.awt package, but it does not import java.awt.color, java.awt.font, or any other java.awt.xxxx packages.

If you plan to use the classes and other types in java.awt.color as well as those in java.awt, you must import both packages with all their files:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.color.*;
```

For more clarity, you can refer this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html)